# implement SMOTEENN in DASK RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: dask, smote

I successfully implemented tuned a model using SMOTEENN and RF in a pipeline. Like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, roc_auc_score, confusion_matrix
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.combine import SMOTEENN
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

After loading data and getting a `X_train`, `X_test`, `y_train`, and `y_test` matrices, I successfully performed sklearn RandomizedSearch like this:

```
seed = 1706
knn = 10
smoted = SMOTE(sampling_strategy = 'auto',
               k_neighbors = knn,
               random_state = seed) 
mydata = pd.read_csv(datapath)
params_rf = {
  'rf__max_depth':[8, 14, 20, 26],
  'rf__min_samples_leaf':[8, 15, 22, 29],
  'rf__max_features':[6, 12, 18, 24, 30],
  'rf__n_estimators':[400, 800]
  }

smote_enn = SMOTEENN(smote = smoted)

rf = RandomForestClassifier(criterion = 'gini')

pipeline = Pipeline([('smote_enn', smote_enn), ('rf', rf)]) #<-pipeline with smote and model steps

random.seed(1706)
grid_rf = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = pipeline,
                             param_distributions = params_rf,
                             scoring = 'roc_auc',
                             cv = 8,
                             n_jobs = cpu_count()-2,
                             refit = True,
                             return_train_score = False,
                             n_iter = 80)
grid_rf.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
```

My question is: can anyone help me figure out why I cannot do the same thing with Dask's RandomizedSearchCV? Here is the code and the error I get:

```
from dask_ml.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV as DaskRandomGridSearchCV
grid_rf = DaskRandomGridSearchCV(estimator = pipeline,
                                 param_distributions = params_rf,
                                 scoring = 'roc_auc',
                                 cv = 8,
                              ###n_jobs = cpu_count()-2, <-not needed b/c of dask
                                 refit = True,
                                 return_train_score = False,
                                 n_iter = 80)
grid_rf.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
AttributeError: 'SMOTEENN' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

Why does it work with sklearn's RandomizedSearchCV but not dask's [RandomizedSearchCV](https://dask-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/generated/dask_ml.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html)?

I upgraded all libraries to their latest version. I'm using Python 3.6.9 (I also tried on another machine running Python 3.7.3 and got the same error).

Comment: I ran into the same problem using Dask's RandomizedSearchCV. Apparently, Dask requires you to implement the `transform()` method for each component, while Sklearn's RandomizedSearchCV does not. I will try to find a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because dask-ml is using sklearn's `Pipeline`, which doesn't handle `fit_resample` and doesn't pass transformed y down the pipeline.

I'd made a PR for dask-ml to handle imblearn components, you can find it here: https://github.com/xKHUNx/dask-ml.

You can pull it as a temporary solution until the PR is accepted.